# SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery locks the table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I am using a C# winform application and I have this code using SQl server:

```
SqlCommand comm;
comm.CommandText = "alter table anyTable add someColumn int null";
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

when I debug this code section, right after the     comm.ExecuteNonQuery();, I want to go to SQL server management and do a "select * " on the relevant table to check on the changes.

Problem is that I can't touch this table, the SQL server "Executing query" for a long time and it wont do it until the connection will be refreshed, but I can accsess another tables.

This problem does not always exists and I cant figure out why it happens.

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your help.

I had an open transaction in one of my SQL scripts...

Answer (score 2):

The target table will be locked until the ALTER TABLE statament is fully completed. The database needs to prevent access to that table in order to maintain integrity.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to add null simple column to a very small table. problem is not permanent and I want to understand what makes it lock.

Comment: What do you mean of "fully completed"?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to create an extra table that references initial table by key?

```
CREATE Original(id int, value1 int PRIMARY KEY(Id))
CREATE Secondary(OriginalId int, ColumnName VARCHAR(50), value INT PRIMARY KEY(OriginalId, ColumnName))

ALTER TABLE Secondary  ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Secondary_Original] FOREIGN KEY([OriginalId] )
REFERENCES Original ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

in this case you will be able to extent Original row content runtime row-wise just by simple INSERT into Secondary table